# sencha touch 2 how to read crossbrowser xml with jsonp

Tags: xml, extjs, proxy, sencha-touch-2, jsonp

I have a little dilemma. I cant seem to find how I can read xml to my list from a crossdomain site using jsonp  (since ajax is only used if the source is on same domain).

I get connected with `proxy:{ type:'jsonp', url:'http://www.aftonbladet.se/rss.xml',reader:{type:'xml',record:'item'}}`

but end up with " Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < rss.xml:1  " in the console.

I have a hunch about creatin some kind of callback but thats it... im a bit stuck.

Any help would be very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

JSONP is not XML. XML is not JSONP. You use one or the other.

There is an XML reader available in Sencha Touch. That may be what you are looking for: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Xml

```
Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: ['id', 'name', 'email']
    }
});

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'User',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'users.xml',
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            record: 'user'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is the comfusing part to me. I now they are not the same. 
But the proxy to use since I am connecting to an external domain can that actually still be ajax? I have read the page you are refering to but they only use xml within same domain.

If I connect with proxy typ: ajax and reader type:xml - I get this error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.aftonbladet.se/rss.xml?_dc=1353171349636&page=1&start=0&limit=25. Origin http://127.0.0.1 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Sencha Touch does not support cross domain XML out of the box.

Comment: thanks for your answers rdougan. You are very correct.
But finally I found a solution for anyone reading this thread having same trouble as me. This is a workaround solution:
**http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?12852-ScriptTagProxy-and-XML)**
or to have a look up sencha kiva.